# Wave equation, PDE Course

Tags: partial-differential-equations, diagonalization

I'm taking a course in PDE's, and I'm trying to understand an example from the course literature, and would like some help.

The example is the following

Example 1: (baby wave equation)

Consider the second order ODE $$f''(t)=-w^2f(t)+a(t)$$

where $a$ is a given function, $w \in \mathbb R$ is a given constant. A way to solve this is to write it a s a $2 \times 2$ system of first order ODE's and solve it by diagonalisation.

Let $u : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ be the vector valued function $u(t) = \begin{bmatrix}f(t) \\ f'(t)\end {bmatrix}$

where it satisfies $u'(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -w^2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}u(t)+\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ a(t) \end{bmatrix}$.

Then the example goes on to diagonalize the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -w^2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and solve it.

My question is, why do we choose $u(t)$ to be what is is? It does not make sense to me what they chosen $u(t)$ to be.

Comment: Actually, it is just a trick to convert a higher-order linear differential equation into a first-order one.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that two initial conditions are needed ($f$ and $f'$), so they are just making those components of a single vector so only a single (vector) initial condition is needed. One then has a first-order vector system that may be easier to analyze